# my two ajax send request at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem about my code. In my program, I have here an option box that will allow the user to choose what page did she/he want to show in my `tblPlank` and `tblSummary` (tblSummary and tblPlank were both jqgrid). Evrytime he chooses a page and click a button, it will call the function `displayPageNum`. Now, my problem is, this two:

`url:'processjson.php?path=' + encodeURI('getData/tally/page') + '&json=' + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(datas)),`

and

`url:'processjson.php?path=' + encodeURI('getReport/tallySummary') + '&json=' + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(datas)),`,

send request at the same time which sometimes makes my other table (or the other) dont display the right output. So how can I fix this to make it send request one at a time?

```
function displayPageNum(){  
 var flag = 0;
  if ($("#page option:selected").text() != 'all'){    
    var datas = {
      "SessionID": $.cookie("SessionID"),
      "dataType":"data",
      "transaction_id":$('.transactionID').attr('id'),
      "page":$("#page option:selected").text()
    };
    $('#tblPlank').setGridParam({
    url:'processjson.php?path=' + encodeURI('getData/tally/page') + '&json=' + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(datas)), 
      datatype: primeSettings.ajaxDataType
    });
    $('#tblPlank').trigger('reloadGrid');     
    flag =1;
    if (flag == 1){
      var datas = {
        "SessionID": $.cookie("SessionID"),
        "dataType":"data",
        "transaction_num":$('.transactionID').val(),
        "page":$("#page option:selected").text()
      };
       $('#tblSummary').setGridParam({
        url:'processjson.php?path=' + encodeURI('getReport/tallySummary') + '&json=' + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(datas)), 
        datatype: primeSettings.ajaxDataType      
      });             
      $('#tblSummary').trigger('reloadGrid');
    }
  }
 }
```

I put the flag variable just to make send the request one at a time, but still sending request at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I could see two ways:

1) Synchronous ajax request or

2) Send other ajax request when first one success.

Normally they are asynchronous.

Comment: yes, I know I have to do it if the first one success. But with the code I have right now, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: In normal ajax calls there should be callback function called success: function() {} in which you could try putting the second ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Even better, you could use **jQuery Deffered** which allows you to have a success callback when both requests have completed.

```
var ajax1 = function (){
    return $.get('first.html');
}

var ajax2 = function (){
     return $.get('second.html');
}

$.when( ajax1(), ajax2()).then(function(){
  alert('Both Done!');
});
```

However if you want to make sure that you cannot send more than 1 request at a time you can keep track of the request object.

```
var myRequest;

var ajaxRequest = function () {
    if (!myRequest) {
        var myRequest = $.get('myWebservice.html');
    }
}
```